# Mount a local directory as volume in container, from the Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I know how local directories can be mounted as volumes with the `-v` option in `docker run`, i.e.

```
docker run -v /local/some_folder:/container/some_folder image_name
```

However, I want to be able to specify the above instruction (to mount the local `/local/some_folder` as `/container/some_folder` in the container **within the Dockerfile**.

---

I've tried using `VOLUME /local/some_folder /container/some_folder` in the `Dockerfile`, but that didn't seem to work: I am then able to access `/container/some_folder` from within the container using `docker exec -t container sh`, but the write changes of container to `/container/some_folder` **are not reflected in `/local/some_folder` during container runtime AND after `docker stop container`.**

Comment: You can do that using [`docker-composer` command](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volume). The instructions should be placed in `docker-compose.yml` though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have access to control things like host volume mounts inside the Dockerfile or image build process. Allowing this would allow malicious image creators to make an image that mounts directories on the host without the permission of the admin of that host. A security breach that allowed a popular base image to mount the filesystem could be used to send private data off-site and inject login credentials on countless machines. The only way to mount a volume is at run time at the explicit request of the admin running the container, and to the directory they provide.